# How to check if varData(0) exists in Access VBA to overcome "Subscript out of range" error?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my program, if `field_to_split` contains the empty string, then I get the following error:

> ```
> Run-time error '9':  
> Subscript out of range
> ```

As a temporary "fix", I have added in `On Error Resume Next` because after trying several different if statements, I cannot figure out how to do a check to ensure that varData is populated at at least index 0.  How could I mitigate the error occurring from this scenario?

Here is the relevant code:

```
Dim varData As Variant
Dim rs      As DAO.Recordset

...

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

...

' Get all comma delimited fields '
varData = Split(rs![field_to_split], ",") 

' Update First Record '
On Error Resume Next
.Edit
!region_split = Trim(varData(0)) ' Remove spaces before writing new fields '
.Update
```

Comment: Test for Ubound and LBound

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` does not "handle" the error.  It explicitly *does not handle it*. See [Error Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3211/error-handling) over on Documentation.

Comment: Comintern: I am aware of that, hence trying to fix this properly.  I'll remove that comment since it was just a temporary measure to suppress the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UBound(varData)>-1` (or `>=0`) to check if it has at least one value. If there is no value, UBound gives -1.

```
Dim varData As Variant
Dim rs      As DAO.Recordset

...

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

...

' Get all comma delimited fields '
varData = Split(rs![field_to_split], ",") 

' Update First Record '
If UBound(varData) > -1 Then
  .Edit
  !region_split = Trim(varData(0)) ' Remove spaces before writing new fields '
  .Update
End If
```

You can also use a For loop:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(varData)
  MsgBox varData(i)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Ubound([array name],[dimension]) function that returns highest number of subscript of the array for dimension. dimension if not specified assumed 1. In your case it is single dimension array to make sure you use last index as
nIndex = Ubound([array name]) -1

```
for nIndex = 0 to Ubound(varData) - 1 
    Debug.Print varData(nIndex)
next
```

[Visual Basic help for more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95b8f22f(v=vs.90).aspx) , [Office Help of UBound](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/UBound-Function-212b1998-327b-4f1e-ba3f-db4f9b5ba251)